# Update top 50 rows from other table

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables

How can you get the top 50 rows from a table and update them into another table where the ID's (rows) may not already exist in the second, the 'to update', table?

By Top 50 I mean the 50 locations (asc) that are not in the CycleCount table already, some background: I would like to store 50 locations (per update) in the table CycleCount. All the locations that exist, are populated in the table Warehouse. Everytime, I'd like to add 50 new locations from warehouse into cyclecount, but the updated locations need to be in ascending order (of warehouse location)

I have tried using UPDATE TOP (50) Table1 SET ... etc. but that doesn't work in this case.

I have this code, but this will update ALL locations (rows) instead of the top 50 (new) locations:

```
DECLARE @N INT 
SET @N = 50
UPDATE CycleCount
SET MagLoc   = items.UserField_06, 
    Itemcode = items.ItemCode,
    CCDate   = GETDATE()
FROM Warehouse LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON Warehouse.Location = items.UserField_06
WHERE WareHouse.Location NOT IN (select MagLoc from CycleCount) 
GO
```

Comment: All tables (warehouse, Cyclecount and items) are in the same database (DB1)

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, TeraData, SyBase, DB2?  All have different syntax and capabilities.

Comment: What do you mean by `top 50`, are you ordering it on some column ?

Comment: Oh sorry, T-SQL (working with SSMS 2008)

Comment: By Top 50 I mean the 50 locations (asc) that are not in the CycleCount table already, some background: I would like to store 50 locations (per update) in the table CycleCount. All the locations that exist, are populated in the table Warehouse. Every time, I'd like to add 50 new locations from warehouse into cyclecount, but the updated locations need to be in ascending order (of warehouse location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the `WITH` key word:

```
;WITH query
AS (
    SELECT TOP 50 *
    FROM [Your Query]
)
UPDATE query
SET MagLoc   = items.UserField_06, 
    Itemcode = items.ItemCode,
    CCDate   = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Yes you can update data on base tables through a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)